# recv() with MSG_PEEK shows full message but returns 'would block' normally

Tags: c++, winsock, recv, peek

I have a non-blocking winsock socket that is `recv`'ing data in a loop.

I noticed that when connecting with, say, putty and a raw socket, sending messages works just fine. However, when interfacing with this particular client, the packets seem to not be triggering a successful, non-`MSG_PEEK` call to `recv`. I recall having a similar issue a few years back and it ended up having to end the packets in `\r` or something coming from the *client*, which isn't possible in this case since I cannot modify the client.

Wireshark shows the packets coming through just fine; my server program, however, isn't working quite right.

How would I fix this?

**EDIT:** Turning the buffer size down to, say, 8 resulted in a few *successful* calls to recv without MSG_PEEK.

Recv call:

```
iLen = recv(group->clpClients[cell]->_sock, // I normally call without MSG_PEEK
        group->clpClients[cell]->_cBuff, CAPS_CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE, MSG_PEEK);
if(iLen != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    ...
```

Socket is `AF_INET`, `SOCK_STREAM` and `IPPROTO_TCP`.

Comment: To confirm that I'm understanding this correctly, are you saying a `recv` with `MSG_PEEK` says a certain number of bytes are available, and then a subsequent `recv` with flags set to zero and with no intervening operations on the socket, blocks?

Comment: I would triple-check that you are meeting every single one of the conditions I stated above. If you are, that's astounding. (You're sure flags is zero on the subsequent `recv`? You're sure it's the same socket? You're sure there are no intervening socket operations? You're sure you got the right return value from `recv` the first time?)

Comment: Wow! Yet another reason not to use `MSG_PEEK`. (Why are you bothering anyway? It just forces you to call `recv` twice.)

Comment: Using `MSG_PEEK` was just for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setsockopt` to set `TCP_NODELAY` to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft documentation states in several places that `MSG_PEEK` should be avoided altogether because it is inefficient and inaccurate.  Use `select()`, `WSAAsyncSelect()`, or `WSASelectEvent()` instead to detect when a socket has data available for reading, then call `recv()` or `WSARecv()` to actually read it.

Comment: Is this been fixed now? I couldn't see anything like this mentioned in Microsoft docs now.

Comment: @samnaction "*Is this been fixed now?*" - no. "*I couldn't see anything like this mentioned in Microsoft docs now*" - because MS's documentation sucks in many ways. This question predates MS's move to learn.microsoft.com, and a lot of good information was lost in the move.

Answer (score 0):

TCP socket is a stream of *bytes*, it does not preserve your application message boundaries. As soon as kernel has *something* to give to you, it returns from the poll. You have to collect received bytes until you have enough to decode whatever you need to decode.

Comment: Yes but a regular call with a buffer that is long enough should return all of the bytes in the buffer.

Comment: What length does the call with `MSG_PEEK` return? Are you sure it's the full "message" and not something that was in the buffer before? Do you set any options on that socket?

Comment: The peek call shows several packets-worth of information piled up. The sizes were accurate and reflected the full, complete message lengths.

Comment: And no, no options other than non-blocking.

Comment: Changing the socket to blocking doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being implementation-specific; I knew the length of *all* packets coming from the client were divisible by a certain amount of bytes. So, I just read that amount of bytes until the buffer was empty.

The max. number of bytes you can receive at a time in this situation must be less than the maximum length of the longest message, and must be the GCF (Greatest Common Factor) of that length.

This is far from a permanent solution, but it works for now.